# Run PHP coming into a mySQL result

Tags: php

This is maybe about the 4 time I ask this question all over the web without having a working solution.

It is driving me crazy.

I will try to make it as easier as possible to understand.

I have some code inside a database table, that looks like this:

```
<div> Hello my name is {$name}</div>

<span> I come from {$city}</span>

<div>I am {$age} years old</div>
```

I repeat, this text come from a mySQL table that  I SELECT with the following code:

```
function getPageContent($page) {
$q='SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page="'.$page.'"';
 $r=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
      $content= $row['Content'];
       }
 return $content;
}
```

As you may see there are some PHP variables in the above code, such as `{$age}` or `{$city}`, they are only samples because I won't know the exact content.

What I need to do is to find a way for PHP to get the contents of the `$content` variable ( string coming from the DB SELECT ), to recognize the variables inside the brackets `{$foo}` as normal PHP variables and to run them before echoing the final code.

As you may see the $content variable may have different and unknown variables inside it, so I must find a way to get those variables whatever they represent.

I do not know if the right thing to use here is `eval()`. But seems that eval() works only with something like `{echo 'value'}` and not with variables `{$foo}`, or `{echo $foo}` because variables won't be recognized at all.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

This is driving me crazy.

The concept is to give to the users the possibility to enter HTML text inside my mySQL DB and to include whatever PHP code they want inside brackets `{}`. This can be very useful for example for multi-language websites..etc..

I hope you understand my point.

Thanks

Comment: You really don't want to let your users execute "whatever PHP code they want".

Comment: Consider using a templating engine such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: I tried with Smarty, but as I see so far, it will require to know the variables and assign them a value. But I do not know the variables inside the content at all.

Comment: You're getting the available variables from somewhere, so don't you know what the possible variables are? You don't need to know what's used in the content. Just substitute them all. If they don't exist, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you provide a sample? I tried, but I cannot abstract the code with Smarty...I am simply new to it and I am wasting a lot of time trying to understand the logic..

Comment: Can you explain how you're getting the list of variables which can be used for substitution?

Comment: I have them defined in a separate file called for example langs/it.php. I want to use as a multi-language system..But I cannot make Smarty works with contents coming from the DB...I do not know how to do it..Example <div id="home">{$lang['homepage']}</div>

Comment: I would strongly suggest defining the variables as an associative array. For example, `langs/it.php` could contain `return array('city'=>'Here', 'name'=>'Steve');`. Then you can get the variables via `$vars = include 'langs/it.php';`. This will make the data much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use eval for this. Just do a simple search and replace.

From your question, tt's hard to understand where exactly the values for `$name`, `$city` and `$age` are stored. So, I'll just start from the point where you've retrieved that info. Let's say it's something like this:

```
$content = '<div> Hello my name is {$name}</div>

<span> I come from {$city}</span>

<div>I am {$age} years old</div>
';

$city = 'Kansas City';

echo str_replace('{$city}', $city, $content);
```

Also, in the sample code you've provided, the `$content` variable keeps getting over-written on each iteration of the `while` loop. Perhaps, that's what you want to happen or perhaps you wish to concatenate it.

### Edit

After reading some of your comments, it seems that you will need a more dynamic solution. You can do so with something along the lines of:

```
if (preg_match_all('/{\$\w+}/', $content, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $var) {
        // var now contains the {$variableName}.
    }
}
```

This will find the variables within your HTML, which you can then loop over, comparing against your file that contains the actual name/value pairs. Then use `str_replace` as shown above.

Comment: It assumes I know which variables are inside the content. But actually I do not know them, because they are inserted by the user. It should be abstract. Your code requires me to specify every single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
<div> Hello my name is <?=$name?></div>

<span> I come from <?=$name?></span>

<div>I am <?=$age?> years old</div>
```

For this to work, of course, you need the [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive enabled. You can accomplish the same thing in more code without this enabled too:

```
<div> Hello my name is <?php echo $name ?></div>

<span> I come from <?php echo $name ?></span>

<div>I am <?php echo $age ?> years old</div>
```

You should really watch out for malicious users gaining access to this script though,  because the way you envisioned it, they would be able to execute any code they so desired. **Be sure to sanitize input and output of this script!**

Comment: Sorry, didn't really warrant a downvote. I was in the middle of writing a comment before you commented. Anyway, my concern with this answer is that it encourages the use of `eval()` on user-submitted text.

Comment: @MichaelMior A legitimate concern, however I believe sanitation of input should take place before retrieving it from the DB. I've added a note in my answer to watch out for this anyway ;)

Comment: I tried both solutions, with and without short_open_tag. The results is nothing or errors.

Comment: @DiegoP. Be descriptive... WHAT do the errors say? Why would you want users to be able to run their own code anyway? Security risks up the wazoo...

Comment: @esqew Agreed that the input should be sanitized. But what about when the next developer comes along and doesn't think about input sanitization and starts dumping things in the same table in the database? I think it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Sorry "errors" was wrong typo. I meant the result is nothing, the variables simply does not get recognized and they get printed as they are ( not processed at all )

Comment: @DiegoP. Did you `eval()` the string?

Comment: @DiegoP. Again, **why would you want users to be able to run their own code anyway?** You are BEGGING for users to compromise your entire system when you `eval()` user input!

Comment: My "USERS" are my collaborators...so I am not worried about security. I just want to find a way to run PHP code stored in the DB and echoing the right result, but eval() does not work for me, it returns empty...

Comment: Also I do not know how to make eval() working for various variables and for whatever variables will be in the content. All the solutions I see require to know which variables will be in the content..but I do not know them..I want the code to be as much abstract as possible

Comment: @DiegoP. Just use `eval($var)`? I don't know what else to tell you.